# Множественное число от слова "колея"

Tags: грамотная-речь, фонетика

Как образовать множественное число от слова "колея": "колеИ" или "кОлеи"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно колеЯ, колеИ.  КОлеи - как-то странно даже.